# Eclipse doesn't recognize new play framework's view's apply method

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework

I started playing around with play framework and got around to frameworks.

I created a view which looks like:

> @(name:String)
>
> < b> @name

and I have a controller which looks like

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok("lol")
  }
  def recent = Action{
    Ok(views.html.Application.recent.render("Hello"))
  }
}
```

when I compile it works completly fine.
However, eclipse complains about me using "render":

```
not enough arguments for method render: (title: String, content: play.twirl.api.Html)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable. Unspecified value parameter content.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the command "eclipse" in the activator command prompt.